# Can my code get the Google map API version number?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am not using the v parm when I load the Google map API.  Therefore I always get the "release" version of the API.

My app has an "About" feature and I would like to display the API version number.

Is there a way for me to get that value or would this be an enhancement request?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

simply use: `google.maps.version`

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/anN4U/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/anN4U/)

Comment: Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: I don't know if it is documented but google.maps.version certainly works.  Thanks

Comment: [related issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8227)

Comment: It is definitely documented now.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Answer (score 0):

There was a way to get it from the filename of the script that loaded:

```
//*************************************************************
// API version from post on Google Maps API group by bratliff
var file,loop;
var tags=document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT");
// alert("tags="+tags.length);

for (loop=0;tags[loop];loop++)
{
       if (file=tags[loop].src.match(/http:\/\/[^\&\?]+\.google\.[^\&\?]+\/([0-9]+)\/[^\&\?]+\/main\.js/)) {
          //alert(file[1]);
          document.getElementById("apiv").innerHTML = "API v2."+file[1];
       }
}
//*************************************************************
```

You should be able to do the something similar for API v3.

Comment: Thanks but in v3 we have the option to *not* specify any v parameter in our script.

Comment: V2 had that option as well.  The script parses the version number out of the actual script that is loaded (which does have a version number).